# Duplicate Contents and Glossary title

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

I am getting duplicates of my glossary and contents titles as shown below.  How can I get rid of the first one?

[image]

Most of my preamble is shown below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfplots,pgfplotstable, acronym, fullpage, booktabs, rotating, multirow, longtable, siunitx, fancyhdr, filecontents, textcomp, gensymb,pdfpages, amsmath, caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % Remove indentation
\usepackage[titletoc, page]{appendix}   % To number appendix in toc
\usepackage[section]{placeins}          % To stop figures floating across sections
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        % For clickable urls
\usepackage{cleveref}                   % To allow \cref to be used
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % Use EC fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Encoding
\usepackage{csquotes}                   % To manage quotes
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Language selection
\usepackage[acronym,toc,style=tree, nonumberlist, shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear,doi=true,url=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please also show the commands you use to generate the table of contents and the glossary? Ie., please don't show the preamble but provide a small working example that generates the problem behavior that needs to be fixed. Incidentally, since you provide the option `toc` while loading the `glossaries` package, you're guaranteed to get a ToC entry for the glosssaries section; do you maybe want to suppress this behavior?

Comment: Yes, removed the toc. Also, while trying to create a 'small working example' I discovered the problem. I was using  
\pagestyle{fancyplain} which was causing this problem. To remove the duplicate title in the header all I had to do was to modify this to:
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{}

Comment: What do I do now btw? Do I delete the question?

Comment: I suggest you post an answer to your own question, in which you post the solution you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

caused this problem. If you are using the `fancyhdr` package to define headers/footers yourself, you need to clear the default layout by declaring

```
\fancyhead{}
```